Accidently stopped git repo clone
I tried to clone a git repo that already exists in wsl (ubuntu).
However, when it asked for password, I forgot it doesn't show on screen, and pressed ctrl+z to try and delete what I wrote. But then I got this message:
[1]+   Stopped               git clone https://<redacted>

It seems that a folder was created in my computer but I don't know if the clone worked.
for now i want to safely delete the folder and do the clone again, not resume it. How do I do that?
is regular delete enough for local repositories?

rm -rf /path/to/directory?

Ctrl-z has paused the current process. fg will bring you back to it (I suppose waiting to type your password). If you can't get back to the git clone from your current terminal, list processes with ps, then kill the one corresponding to git clone. You'll then be able to delete your folder.

hi thank you, good to know regarding ctrl+z. i will edit the question- i want to know how to delete safely because i am not sure if regular delete is enough when it comes to local repositories.

What other delete might there be besides "regular"?

BTW to abort a process, press Ctrl-C, not Ctrl-Z

i don't know. of course delete seems simple but since it is my first time using git i dont know if the remote repo will be affected or if by deleting my local folder it could affect other files on the computer or if they are attached somehow.

Why do you think the folder will be attached to others?
